# Link to component appears empty

Tags: component, joomla-4.x, custom-component

I created a simple component, which appears as expected at the admin side.

If I link the component using a menu item, everything seems to be finde. Component appears in selector, component's views appear as selectable items. No errors when saving the menu item.

the **menu item editor** shows this link just fine:

```
index.php?option=com_eventcalendar&view=featured
```

But if I reload the front-end, the menu item appear with **no path component**.

It just shows the link `http://localhost/JTestFolder/`, and not this one: `http://localhost/JTestFolder/index.php?option=com_eventcalendar&view=featured`

**But why doe the parameters get lost??**

Additionally, I installed to MyWalk sample extension. Works just fine.

It does generate a SEF `/KPFJoomla/index.php/walks2`.

I searched the extension's code for walks or walks2, but failed. How does this short hand URL gets generated?

Comment: Do you have a  ..\components\com_inventory\src\Service\Router.php defined in the front end?

Comment: That solved it. Thx! If you provide an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to have a ..\components\com_inventory\src\Service\Router.php defined in the front end?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the SEF Url's. If (JTestFolder) is your namespace in your provider, then it can potentially be Search Engine Friendly URL.

TO disable:

To test if this is the issue, you can try disabling SEF URLs in Joomla's Global Configuration. To do this, go to System > Global Configuration > SEO Settings and set "Search Engine Friendly URLs" to "No". Save your changes and then reload the front-end to see if the issue persists.

Comment: This does disable SEO link, as I see in the MyWalks sample extension. But still, my extension linked to a menu item doesn't get the path / parameter path set.

Comment: Am I right regarding my expectation, that I need to implement a router class to implement SEF?

Comment: Yes. You need to add a RouterService to your provider, register it and setup the rules for your SEF URL's.